# compiling HTML fragments for Single Page Application (SPA)?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

Javascript Single Page Applications (SPA's) make it possible to create powerful web applications with simple technology. As an SPA becomes bigger, it seems you would need to have a way to separate the content in multiple html (and javascript an css) files to keep things manageable and maintainable.

All examples of how to make such a bigger application seem to make use of a separate templating mechanism such as JSP or Asp.net MVC, to combine html fragments into a single html page served to the client. To me this seems like overkill for an SPA, so that leads me to the question:

*Is there a framework or tool(set) that allows me to compile html fragments into an html file that I can deploy to a static web server without requiring a dynamic server like IIS or Tomcat?*

The assumption here is that there is a web (REST) API available for the SPA to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at these types of frameworks / libraries?

- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)
- [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)
- [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/)

To name but only those i'm aware of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These frameworks are very powerful but I don't see how they offer a solution to my issue. If I have an application with tabs and many different 'panels', I would want to 'componentize' it in files, so they can be maintained independently in source control, perhaps edited by different developers and tested separately. But in an SPA you would like to send it to the browser as a single html page. I'm looking for tooling that will help me achieve this as a step in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://boilerplatejs.org/ - it implements the MVVM pattern and utilizes RequireJS and its text plug-in to neatly break out your views, styles, and view models.

I use this in an Asp.Net MVC 4 solution. [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) is another option, in fact John Papa has recently put out a Visual Studio template called [Hot Towel](https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel). That's also another option.