# Navigating in a single page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a two html pages. One is **Login.html** and another one is **index.html**. Whenever user click on the login button I want to navigate to the **index.html**(but not as an normal href linking).

The index page should be inside the codes of login.html too.. Its like a single page navigation.

Is there any plugin which does the same?

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function hideDiv() {
      document.getElementById("container").style.display = 'none';    
    }  

    function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('container').style.display = "block";
}


        </script>
```

HTML page

```
            <div class="masthead">
                <h3 class="muted">
                <sapn class="login-logo"><img src="img/QuadAnalytix_reg350x47.png"/>
                </span></h3>
            </div>

            <div id="loginformcontainer">

                <form>
                    <label> Username:
                        <input type="text" name="uname">
                    </label>
                    <label> Password:
                        <input type="password" name="pwd">
                    </label>
                    <div class="buttons1">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" class="btn" onclick="showDiv()">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                        <button type="reset"  id="reset" value="Reset"  class="btn">
                            Clear All
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div>




<div id="container">

//index.html page

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows the login page on load but,
When I click the button it shows the container div only for a second.. What should I do here?

Comment: this is confusing.. why do you need that ??

Comment: `onclick="location.href('index.html')"` something like this?

Comment: ? Its likek ksinglke page navigation. ?

Comment: The question is not asked very well. What have you tried? Can we see some code? The alternative would be to have login.html with all the markup and load the content from index.html using ajax when the login is successful.

Comment: http://localhost/foldername....this url defultly browser takes index.html better u try this u dont need login.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX and some Javascript to archieve that.

For example, something like:

HTML:

```
<div id = "index">
    <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="login"></input>

    <div id="login" style="display: none;">
         Welcome to the site.
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY):

```
$('#loginButton').click(function() {
    $.post('login.php', function(data) { // HERE YOU LOGIN
       $('#login').show();
    });
);
```

Comment: @Ash You are using an `input type="submit"`. When you submit your form the page reloads, and it comes back to the first stage where the DIV is hidden. That's why you have to use AJAX instead, so you don't reload the page, or if you want to reload, then you will have to use a returned variable from the server to know when to show or hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load)

like,

```
$('body').load('index.html', function() {
   alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using AJAX functionality. If you can elaborate your problem with code so i can try to help you with the code you can use.

Simplest way to load another page within same is:-

```
$('body').load('index.html', function() {
   alert('Page loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to approach a SPA (single page application)

Check out this SO question: [compiling HTML fragments for Single Page Application (SPA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555444/compiling-html-fragments-for-single-page-application-spa)

you can take a look at http://requirejs.org/
and http://durandaljs.com/

or use john papa's **hot towel**
http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/

> Hot Towel: Because you don’t want to go to the SPA without one!